# 'Collection type for payload data type MSG_TYPE does not exist.'

Tags: c#, oracle, message-queue, devart

I am dequeueing an Oracle Advanced Queue succesfully through the following code:

```
OracleQueue oracleDequeueQueue = new OracleQueue("QUEUENAME", oracleConnection);
OracleQueueMessage msg = oracleDequeueQueue.Dequeue();

if (msg != null && msg.ObjectPayload != null)
{
    Convert.ToString(msg.ObjectPayload["ID"])
}
```

When i try to gather a queue array through the next code snippet, i am receiving the error message

> System.Exception: 'Collection type for payload data type
>   SCH.MDM_MESSAGE_TYPE does not exist.'

```
OracleQueue oracleDequeueQueue = new OracleQueue("QUEUENAME", oracleConnection);
OracleQueueMessage[] msgArr = oracleDequeueQueue.DequeueArray(10);

foreach (OracleQueueMessage m in msgArr)
{
    if (m != null && m.ObjectPayload != null)
    {
        Convert.ToString(m.ObjectPayload["ID"]));
    }
}
```

I have also tried to add the following but this also does not work:

oracleDequeueQueue.PayloadTypeName = "SCH.MDM_MESSAGE_TYPE";
oracleDequeueQueue.PayloadArrayTypeName = "SCH.MDM_MESSAGE_TYPE_ARRAY";

Whats wrong with my code?

This is the Queue Code in Oracle:

```
create or replace type mdm_message_type as object ( id number(12 ) );

create or replace TYPE mdm_message_type_array as table of    mdm_message_type;

exec DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE_TABLE(     Queue_table        => '"SCH"."MDM_CUSTOMER_T"',     Queue_payload_type => 'SCH.MDM_MESSAGE_TYPE');
exec DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE(     Queue_name          => 'SCH.MDM_CUSTOMER',     Queue_table         => 'SCH.MDM_CUSTOMER_T',     Queue_type          =>  0,     Max_retries         =>  10000,     Retry_delay         =>  0,     dependency_tracking =>  FALSE);
exec dbms_aqadm.start_queue( 'SCH.MDM_CUSTOMER',true,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the DequeueArray method, you must have the following array type in Oracle:

```
CREATE TYPE MESSAGE_ARRAY IS VARRAY (100) OF MESSAGE_TYPE_NAME
```

Please note that length of the array of MESSAGE_TYPE_NAME created in Oracle should be equal or greater then the value of the parameter in the DequeueArray method in your .NET code.